# Python3: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Now I am reading a large number(about 1 million rows) of training data(label: 0 or 1) from txt file to practise the machine learning with scikit-learn: the data like the following data:

```
label       data
0      xd,xw,gh
1      xg,xh,xl,xk,yh,xd
```

......................................

But there is error after I run my code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  X, y = get_minibatch(train_text, train_label, chunksize=1000)
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2
```

Please give me you suggestions about this issue!
Thanks for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_minibatch(train_x, train_y, chunksize)` is using yield rendering it an **generator/iterator**.

You are calling it like a **function**, expecting two arguments and unpack them.

But you are not getting two elements, you obtain **one generator/iterator-object** after calling. (In these cases: always print out `print(type(function()))`. Of course this single object can't be unpacked into two.

You need to use it like an generator/iterator, e.g. in python3:

```
X, y = next(get_minibatch(train_text, train_label, chunksize=1000))
```

Comment: thanks   @sascha, after I do add next(get_minibach.....), the code is still have error: raise ValueError("classes should include all valid labels that can "
ValueError: classes should include all valid labels that can be in y

Comment: That's some **new unrelated problem**. The basic problem is, that there are unknown labels as your fitter do not know them. Read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning). Excerpt: ```For classification, a somewhat important thing to note is that although a stateless feature extraction routine may be able to cope with new/unseen attributes, the incremental learner itself may be unable to cope with new/unseen targets classes. In this case you have to pass all the possible classes to the first partial_fit call using the classes= parameter.```

Comment: thanks @sascha your valuable advice. I am sorry I still don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Open up a new question for that. This one is answered (although not accepted). It just does not feel right to discuss this other problem within some comments on an unrelated problem. (Short solution: just build a set(), iterate over all y's, collect all targets, convert to array and pass it to partial_fit using the classes= param)

Comment: thanks @sascha, I will start a new question, and I will accept this.

Comment: @tktktk0711 Just one more thing. I just saw that your are using ```classes = np.array([0, 1])```, so double-check the content of your y. There has to be something else than 0,1. The only other options is some kind of problem due to types (float, int).

Comment: thanks! I am sorry I can't start new question since I can start new question after 90 minutes

Comment: Then you will have to wait and use your time to double check every value and it's type within y.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136566/discussion-between-tktktk0711-and-sascha).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136596/discussion-between-tktktk0711-and-sascha).

Comment: hi @ sascha could you answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451686/python3-classification0-or-1-with-scikit-learn-how-to-improve-the-accuracy-o